# Solana wallets transaction failing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, solana, solana-web3js

I am using [solana_wallet_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/solana_wallet_adapter) to launch any installed Solana wallet like Solflare & Phantom to approve a transaction to send SOL from the user's account to an address I've given.

Following is my code triggered on a button click

```
final adapter = SolanaWalletAdapter(
              const AppIdentity(),
              cluster: Cluster.devnet,
            );

            final Cluster cluster = Cluster.devnet;

            var blockHash = await web3.Connection(cluster).getLatestBlockhash();

            final connection = web3.Connection(
              cluster,
            );


            AuthorizeResult result = await adapter.authorize();


            final connectedAccount = adapter.connectedAccount?.address;
            if (connectedAccount == null) throw Exception('Connect wallet before sending tx.');

            // Mobile wallet displays the address as base-58.
            final rcv = web3.PublicKey.fromBase58("<some-address-here>");

            // Mobile wallet adapter specification returns address as base-64
            final snd = web3.PublicKey.fromBase64(connectedAccount);

            print('creating transaction');

            // Get latest blockhash info.
            final blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

            // Create transfer tx.
            final transaction = web3.Transaction(
              feePayer: snd, // The account that will sign the tx (and pay any fees).
              recentBlockhash: blockhash.blockhash,
              lastValidBlockHeight: blockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
              instructions: [
                SystemProgram.transfer(
                  fromPublicKey: snd,
                  toPublicKey: rcv,
                  lamports: web3.solToLamports(1),
                ),
              ],
            );

            // Serialize tx.
            const config = web3.SerializeConfig(requireAllSignatures: false);
            final tt = transaction.serialize(config).getString(web3.BufferEncoding.base64);
            print('creating transaction string $tt');

            // Sign and send tx.
            final txresult = await adapter.signAndSendTransactions(transactions: [tt]);

            // Wait for confirmation.
            await connection.confirmTransaction(base64ToBase58(txresult.signatures.first!));
```

Phantom shows the option to allow the wallet connection & then shows a bottom sheet to approve the transaction. Upon clicking Approve, nothing happens and after some time the following error is logged in the console `E/flutter (28131): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [JsonRpcException<dynamic>] -3 : sign request declined`

When trying with Solflare, the wallet is connected and when I swipe to approve the transaction, it says unknown error occurred. While Solflare is loading the transaction details and launching, the following errors get logged in console

```
E/flutter (29334): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method callAsyncJavaScript on channel com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_168366115180104102312519725021323649227251)
E/flutter (29334): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #1      InAppWebViewController.callAsyncJavaScript (package:flutter_inappwebview/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:2300)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #2      StakingService.getStakeAccounts (package:solflare/blockchain/solana/sdk/action/staking/staking_service.dart:22)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #3      StakingFragmentCubit._getStakingAccounts (package:solflare/staking/fragment/bloc/staking_fragment_cubit.dart:62)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #4      StakingFragmentCubit.onReload (package:solflare/staking/fragment/bloc/staking_fragment_cubit.dart:56)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): 
E/flutter (29334): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method callAsyncJavaScript on channel com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_168366115180104102312519725021323649227251)
E/flutter (29334): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #1      InAppWebViewController.callAsyncJavaScript (package:flutter_inappwebview/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:2300)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #2      SolanaSimulation.getSimulatedBalanceChanges (package:solflare/blockchain/solana/sdk/action/simulation/solana_simulation.dart:22)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #3      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #4      ConfirmTransactionCubit._loadSimulationInitially (package:solflare/transaction/bloc/confirm_transaction/confirm_transaction_cubit.dart:150)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): 
E/flutter (29334): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method callAsyncJavaScript on channel com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_168366115180104102312519725021323649227251)
E/flutter (29334): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #1      InAppWebViewController.callAsyncJavaScript (package:flutter_inappwebview/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:2300)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #2      NameService.getTwitterHandleForPublicKey (package:solflare/blockchain/solana/sdk/action/name_service/name_service.dart:28)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #3      PortfolioCubit._getTwitterHandle (package:solflare/portfolio/fragment/bloc/portfolio_cubit.dart:227)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #4      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #5      PortfolioCubit._getPortfolioData (package:solflare/portfolio/fragment/bloc/portfolio_cubit.dart:143)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #6      PortfolioCubit.setTokenAccountCubit.<anonymous closure> (package:solflare/portfolio/fragment/bloc/portfolio_cubit.dart:130)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): 
E/flutter (29334): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method callAsyncJavaScript on channel com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_2266535125213471107817222715523920315117744)
E/flutter (29334): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #1      InAppWebViewController.callAsyncJavaScript (package:flutter_inappwebview/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:2300)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #2      ActivityService.initialize (package:solflare/blockchain/solana/sdk/action/activity/activity_service.dart:32)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): #3      TokenAccountCubit._onRefresh (package:solflare/shared/bloc/token_account/token_account_cubit.dart:95)
E/flutter (29334): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29334): 
E/flutter (28131): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [SolanaException<SolanaWalletAdapterExceptionCode>] SolanaWalletAdapterExceptionCode.sessionClosed : The web socket has been disconnected.
```

Comment: Did you try to delete and reinstall the app form your device/emulator? Otherwise, MissingPluginException just says that the plugin is not supported on your device

Comment: Yes, I'm on a Redmi 9 Power Android 11 device running MIUI Global 12.5.11. Still, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue but i was able to make this work on android by converting base58 to base64
Here is my signMessage function, hope this helps:-

```
void _signMessages() async {
const String description = "Sign Messages";
try {
  debugPrint("Create $description... account base58 ${solanaWalletAdapter?.connectedAccount?.addressBase58}");
  final List<String> messages = List.generate(1, (index) => base64Encode('Sign message $index'.codeUnits));
  debugPrint("description -> $description...");
  SignMessagesResult? result = await solanaWalletAdapter?.signMessages(
    messages: messages,
    addresses: [base58ToBase64(solanaWalletAdapter!.connectedAccount!.addressBase58)],
  );

  debugPrint("Signed Messages ${result?.signedPayloads.join('\n')}");
} catch (error, stack) {
  print('$description Error: $error');
  print('$description Stack: $stack');
  debugPrint("catch error in sign ${error.toString()}, $stack");
}
```

}